# Datatables.js different column priority on target row than others

Tags: javascript, datatables, responsive

I have a table with thead and tbody. Everything works fine, but on target row, i have only 2 data, the rest are empty, i want to priotize those 2 non-empty columns while viewing in mobile first. I want third column and sixth column to be higher priorities. The row has class 'my_own'.

```
function initializeDataTable(tableId) {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#' + tableId)) {
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().destroy();
    }
    
    $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"],
        "order": [],
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "<?= $lang['no_result']?>",
            "search": "<?= $lang['search_here'] ?>"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 3 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 2 },
            { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 0 },
            { responsivePriority: 4, targets: 5 },
            { responsivePriority: 5, targets: 4 },
            { responsivePriority: 6, targets: 1 }
//if the row class is 'my_own', show third and sixth column with higher priority
        ]


    });



}
```

What ive tried:
I tried to hide empty columns, but it messed with other rows above
I tried to merge columns, same effect

I want entire table to be responsive as the code above, but make an exception for target row